# AngularJS dropdown is not selecting

Tags: angularjs

```
<select ng-model="vm.pageNumber" ng-change="someFunction()">
  <option ng-repeat="page in vm.pagesIds" ng-value="page">
    Page {{page}}
  </option>
</select>
```

So, `pageNumber` is a number of current page (`1`). `pagesIds` is an array of pages' (`[1,2,3]`)numbers. I cant get it, why on page refresh it doesn't select page? All the functionality is working, pages are being changed, but unfortunately `select`'s selected field is always empty. I've tried using `ng-value='page'` and `value={{page}}` but still doesn't work. 
Even initial `vm.pageNumber = 1` is not showing, `select` has empty field, though dropdown contains all the options.

Any tips, please?

**UPDATE:**
When I try to `ng-selected='vm.pageNumber == page'` it works only for last option `3`.

Comment: Did you try `ng-init="vm.pageNumber = 1"`?

Comment: @KKKKKKKK still nothing :(

Comment: somehow it works for Angular material's `md-select`

Comment: Have you tried using `ng-options` ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, somehow same stuff works for Angular Material's `md-select`. Not the proper solution, but it works. https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdSelect

Answer (score 0):

```
<select ng-model="vm.pageNumber" ng-options="page as page for page in vm.pageIds" ng-change="someFunction()"></select>
```

Setting your vm.pageNumber will set the drop down value.